# Blocking public documents folder for write access?

Tags: c#, windows-10, group-policy, special-folders, public-folders

In the last time I've seen a rising number of customer PCs (Windows 10/11), where my c# software was not able to write in a subfolder of `C:\users\public\documents`, although the user running it is able to manually write there. In a few cases I've identified Bitdefender as culprit, but in most of them, it was not installed.

Are there other ways to "protect" this folder? Is there maybe also a group policy or something?

Answer (score 1):

After wondering for years, one of the customers finally told me, what he did to cause this problem: He activated [Controlled Folder Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/defender-endpoint/controlled-folders?view=o365-worldwide) from Microsoft Defender.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 11 I had to do the opposite to Florian Straub - I had Controlled Folder Access enabled and disabling it helped
So go to "Windows Security" => "Virus & threat protection" => "Virus & threat protection settings" => "Manage settings" => "Controlled folder access" => "Manage Controlled folder access" and switch off "Controlled folder access"